# D3: attrTween not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a sunburst in d3 v3 based on the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307). I'm not able to understand why the attrTween() is not working in in the following case.

```
path.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function(d, i) {
      var p = i
          ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
          : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
      return p
    };
  })
```

I'm getting the following error when clicking any of the arc.

> Error:  attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function (t) { x…".

However, defining a function `arcTween()` as following and calling like this `.attrTween("d", arcTween(d))` is working fine.

```
function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));return arc(d); };
 };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working code uses a function declaration to define `function arcTween(d) { }`. Using this function in `.attrTween("d", arcTween(d))` will actually execute that function passing in the argument `d` from the enclosing function `click(d)`, which is the datum bound to the element the user clicked upon. This call is used to capture/close over that value `d` in the interpolators `xd`, `yd`, and `yr`, which in turn are used in the returned inner function. This returned function is the one which is executed by `.attrTween()` to return the interpolator used for the transition.

In your code, while trying to inline the function declaration, you are missing out on the above mentioned call to the outer function. Therefore, you end up with an invalid return value because your functions are too deeply nested.

There is, however, a simple remedy to make your code work: just add a `(d)` after the inline function to execute it much like the former code does.

```
function click(d) {             // This d is what needs to be captured

  path.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      // var...                // This is where the outer d is closed over/captured
      return function(d, i) {  // This is another d not to be confused with the outer one
        // ...
      };
    }(d))                      // This will execute the function passing in click's d

}
```

Have a look at the updated [Plunk](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/f41f0a17d6f2bf9f41ab7df841aeda22) for a working demo.